# How to wisely use FirebaseFirestoreSwift with Carthage?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

I'm looking for a way `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` and Carthage to coexist.

I'm using `FirebaseFirestore` and `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` and other Firebase frameworks.
There are usually use Cocoapods, but the build is very heavy and take long time.

So I trying to use Carthage.

Fortunately I found public carthage  [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md).
I was able to convert to using Firebase frameworks to carthage by this.
But there isn't `FirebaseFirestoreSwiftBinary`.

I used Cocoapods only for `FirebaseFirestoreSwift`, because it could not be helped.
But it downloaded and built even the related `FirebaseFirestore`, erasing the benefits of Carthage.

Then i tried to download *podspec* and use local podspec with unset dependency as shown here: 
[FirebaseFirestoreSwift](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseFirestoreSwift.podspec). I deleted line 39.

But this way is failed. failed to build.
Because FirebaseFirestoreSwift has `import FirebaseFirestore`

I want to use `$ {SRCROOT} /Carthage/Build/iOS/FirebaseFirestore.framework` but can't figure out a good way.

Does anyone have a good idea or a successful way?

Answer (score 1):

The steps to build the binary are as follows:

- Download this folder and unzip it https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk
- Navigate into the ZipBuilder folder `/firebase-ios-sdk-master/ReleaseTooling/Sources/ZipBuilder`
- Create the following file `pods.json` which contains:

```
[
  {
    "name": "FirebaseFirestoreSwift"
  }
]
```

- Next we need to run the `ZipBuilder` tool to build the binaries. [Docs for ZipBuilder.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/ab7216e357d5a97aaf5a1e3c28666d2d5b1ea7ff/ReleaseTooling/README.md).
- The following command `swift run zip-builder --zip-pods $(pwd)/pods.json` will build the `FirebaseFirestore.swift` for a variety of different architecture. further information on how to use ZipBuilder can be found using `swift run zip-builder --help`

Answer (score 0):

The `cocoapods-binary` plugin is an approach to speed up the build by caching pre-built frameworks.  See details at https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/349#issuecomment-562318371

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase's [ZipBuilder](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/ZipBuilder) tool to create the binaries. Essentially you need to create the `.xcframework` for the pods you need and then either import them directly into your project or create a Carthage repo that hosts the binaries.

You'll need to create a JSON file telling ZipBuilder which pods you want to create:

```
//Pods.json
[
  {
    "name": "FirebaseFirestoreSwift"
  }
]
```

Then run ZipBuilder:

`swift run ReleasePackager -templateDir $(pwd)/Template -zipPods Pods.json`